# Objects referencing each other in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Game
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
     public string Genre { get; set; }
     public Console Console { get; set; }
}

public class Console
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
     public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

After this I added a GameController with scaffolding. Now I am working on the Create view of the Game Object and I am experiencing the problem that the MVC HTML.helpers are rendering input fields for all of the properties of a Console object instead of the just the title (which I guess is logical, given the fact that the property is an actual Console object).

I still want the user to choose a console to be taken along for the Game Object being created, so I tried solving it in the following way:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Console, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Console.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Console.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought I would simply mention the title property of the model, but I'm still receiving input fields for all the Console properties in my Game's create view.
I understand this is simply the way MVC works. But how should I deal with something like this? I also tried things like:

```
Console: @Html.DropDownList("console", "All")
```

Of course the problem here is that the HTML form does not understand that this field is meant to be taken along as the console field for the game object being created. What is the correct solution for this problem?

EDIT:
I did the following:
Add a gameCreation viewModel:

```
 public class GameCreation
    {
        public Game game { get; set; }
        public SelectList Consoles { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I built my ViewModel and passed it to view via controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var gc = new GameCreation();
        gc.Consoles = cb.BuildList(db);      
        return View(gc);
    }
```

Note that cb.BuildList(db) returns a SelectList item. Then in the view I tried:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Console.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("console", gc.Consoles)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Console.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

This does not work, as gc is not known. I also tried passing the data via the ViewBag but this item is also not known here. Also I then received the error:
HTMLHelper has no applicable method named 'dropdownlist'. How can I access the data of the viewmodel which I passed?

Comment: `Game` should have a navigation property `int ConsoleId` and you need a dropdownlist in the view which binds to `ConsoleId`

Comment: Ah all right. So should I never bind objects this way, by making them properties of each other? This is what I was used to in typescript and was in my understanding one of the OOP ways. But the coupling with IDs feels more of a database approach to me then an object oriented approach. Or am I missing/thinking wrong here?

Comment: How about this `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Console,`, Shouldn't this be just `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Console.Title,`??

Comment: Your editing data so step 1 is to create a view model which will contain properties `int SelectedConsole` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ConsoleList` for the dropdownlist.