# Not receiving data from Create View in MVC when using viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
 public class GamesController : Controller
    {
        private AppDBContext db = new AppDBContext();
        private ConsoleBuilder cb = new ConsoleBuilder();

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var gc = new GameCreation();
            gc.Consoles = cb.BuildList(db);       
            return View(gc);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Console")] Game game)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Games.Add(game);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(game);
        }
```

Relevant portion of create view:

```
@model MyOwnWebsiteASP4dot6.ViewModels.GameCreation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Game</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.game.Genre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.game.Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.game.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.game.Console, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
              @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Console.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.game.Console, Model.Consoles)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.game.Console.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Now I put a breakpoint at the start of the [HttpPost] Create function. At this point I receive all data, except the Console is null. (note that cb.BuildList returns a simple selectlist built for testing this. The list is loaded correctly into the view).

Why does this not work?

Classes:

```
public class Game
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public Console Console { get; set; }
    }

public class Console
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }

public class GameCreation
    {
        public Game game { get; set; }
        public SelectList Consoles { get; set; }
    }
```

The sole reason for the GameCreation class is that I want to have access to the Consoles in my view, so that I can create a dropdownlist for the user to select one of the consoles

Comment: Please can you explain more clearly the expected behaviour and what isn't happening that you want to happen

Comment: Well I want to create new Game objects. So when I click the submit in the create view shown above, I expect to receive all the form's input fields as properties of the Game object which is the input for the HttpPost Create function. I do receive all form fields, except the Console property. I other words: The create view itself contains all data and is correct. It however does not send all the data back to the HttpPost create method.

Comment: Ok, cool so you're missing the Console data.  Can you show the structure of `Game` and `Console`

Comment: The model in your view is `GameCreation` which means the model in your post method also needs to be `GameCreation`, not `Game`.

Comment: Well spotted that man!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, but even if I return the GameCreation object, the returned data stays exactly the same (all params except Console). This problem arose from wanting a Game object, which has a Console object as a property. Perhaps Im not using the correct way to reference/bind objects together here?

Comment: You need to delete that awful bind attribute. Then read [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). A view model should not contain properties which are data models

Comment: And  read my comments to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343431/objects-referencing-each-other-in-net-mvc). You model requires a property `int SelectedConsole` to bind the selected `Console` to. You cannot bind a `<select>` (which posts back a single value) to a complex object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I did, that's why I created a viewModel in the first place. I guess my confusion comes from referencing the objects via an int instead of the objects. But now I see why (because of the binding which you just mentioned). Thanks for the clearance!

Comment: `GameCreation` should contain properties `string Title`, `DateTime ReleaseDate`, `string Genre`, `int SelectedConsole` and `SelectList Consoles` (and `int? ID` if you aslo use it for editing)

Answer (score 0):

Change your model in the create post method to `GameCreation`. Like the code below

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Console")] GameCreation game)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Games.Add(game);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(game);
        }
```

because you are sending `GameCreation` model from create get method and in view page you are using the same model. but in the post method you are using different model `Game`. Thats the problem.

Comment: Hey anad, I tried this (along with changing the Bind annotation to include the GameCreation's game and Consoles property. But I still do not receive the Console data. I do receive the other data. I will edit my main question to include the Console and game classes.